# Angular - unexpected token error when colon in time string

Tags: json, angularjs

Here is my error:

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 3 of the expression [06:20] starting at [:20].

The output is a JSON time string, eg: **"5:30"**

My HTML:

```
<input value="{{details.order.earlyPickup}}" ng-model="details.order.earlyPickup">
```

I can't figure out how to fix this so I don't get the error, can anyone help?

Comment: What does `details.order.earlyPickup` JSON look like? Are there quotes around the time?  it should be `"6:20"` not `6:20`

Comment: Can provide your angular code ?

Comment: You don't need value attribute while you are binding your control with model try like this `<input  ng-model="details.order.earlyPickup">`

Comment: Thanks for your replies everyone. The issue ended up being a conflict with the Kendo library we are using. I didn't realise about not needing the value, Anik, so thanks for letting me know. I'm quite new to Angular.